# Smoke doesn't seem to have initial velocity

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29yfS-icS3M) tutorial on how to make a simple explosion, I am using the same values, but I don't get the same effect.

It seems like my particles have no initial velocity.

Do you know what could cause this problem?

Updated .blend file:
[image]

His explosion:
[image: His explosion]

My explosion:
[image: My explosion]

My explosion after James' tips:
[image: My explosion 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Increasing the source under Initial Velocity seems to help. I set it to 25 and it looks similar to his results.

Comment: To be honest, by now I forgot about this project, but yes, that works.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited per our conversation below]...

I think blender is indeed having a problem with its cache.

Aside: I see you have disk cache vs. memory cache for Plane.001 vs Plane.002; perhaps your just trying various combinations.

Try:

1. deleting your 'blendcache_smoke_test' and 'cache_fluid_4b85f272' cache folders
2. In scripting, click on New and cc/paste and run the following script (also in the attached blend file) that should create things in the correct order (finding and running all PS sims before Fluid sims).

```
import bpy
import time

bakedItemCount=0
startTime=time.time()
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for object in scene.objects:
        for modifier in object.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM':
                print("Baking particles for ", object.name)
                override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': object, 'point_cache': modifier.particle_system.point_cache}
                bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(override)
                bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=True)   
                bakedItemCount+=1
    for object in scene.objects:
        for modifier in object.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'FLUID':
                if modifier.fluid_type == 'DOMAIN':
                    print("Baking fluid for ", object.name)
                    object.select_set(True)
                    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
                    bpy.ops.fluid.bake_data()
                    bakedItemCount+=1
            elif modifier.type == 'CLOTH':
                print("Baking cloth for ", object.name)
                override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': object, 'point_cache': modifier.point_cache}
                bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(override)
                bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=True)
                bakedItemCount+=1
                

endTime=time.time()
duration = int((endTime - startTime)+.999)
print( bakedItemCount, ' items baked over ', duration, ' seconds')
```

[image]

Frame 16 rendered with max samples = 16 to reduce render time:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi James, I've tried your suggestions, but it still looks almost the same. The smoke that the particles spawn don't seem to have any velocity, and are just a puff of fire and smoke. I have no idea what could cause this.
I've updated the post with a new image and the new blend file. (now on Blend-Exchange)

Comment: I actually think that this is a bug, I've been doing some tests. [Here is my test scene.](https://blend-exchange.com/b/w0e8xVMD/) If you bake the weird domain first, both simulations will have no initial velocity, but if you bake the correct one first, both will look good. The difference between the two is the flow source of the cube, the incorrect is from the volume and the correct is from the surface. Do you think I should report this somewhere?

Comment: @Matthias -- you would certainly have to bake the PSs first, as then the PS drives the *position* of the particles that the fire'n'smoke are based upon.  I do not think that is a bug per se: it is a procedural workflow that is perhaps a bit arcane.   Have you reviewed the tutorial to see if you had missed a step or if that was not covered?  Does my video look anything like what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, I've baked the PSs, I changed all the thing that you've suggested. And also yes, I've reviewed the tutorial step by step. And the problem is that I can't really see, because my video looks the same at 32 resolution divisions. I think that if you'd render one frame at like 192, you'd get the same effect as me. Like the smoke that the particles spawn don't have velocity and are technically just a static sphere with a geometry inflow, not like in the tutorial.

Comment: If you don't know what I could do to change this, maybe I'll follow the tutorial again tomorrow, but with an older version of blender. Maybe that'll help to discover the root of the problem.

Comment: @Matthias -- your simulation and last frame are set to 100, so did you mean to render frame 92 and not 192 (where console says `Cycles error: unexpected smoke volume resolution, skipping`)? Okay I redid with your orig file and there is no fire/smoke rendering, while in my blend there is... we should compare and look for differences.  You'll see I supplied mine.

Comment: @Matthias -- It appears to be a caching problem.  I was able to recreate the problem of no smoke.  I edited my above answer to mention zapping your cache folders, and running sims in scripted order.

Comment: So I watched the tutorial again, using the same version as him, and it still looks the same. I run the scrips and deleted the cache, still the same. Actually your first image kind of looks like mine, but it is still completely different from what the guy in the tutorial achieved. To be honest, I'm getting tired of this problem, and I think I'll just give up. I don't know how he achieved that explosion, you couldn't achieve it, I couldn't, I don't think anybody could. I won't close this thread in case some particles or VFX pro stumbles upon my problem. But all in all, thanks for trying to help.